# better way to encapsulate commands with parameters

Tags: java, encapsulation

I have a impl class which has several methods, they all basically call the script using runtime.exec with different argument list e.g.

```
public String doExport(String ruleIds, String fileName) throws Exception{
        StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer();
        cmd.append(SOME_SCRIPT + " -a export ");
        cmd.append(" -f " );
        cmd.append(fileName);
        cmd.append(" -r " );
        cmd.append(ruleIds);
        cmd.append(" 2>/dev/null");
        return execCmd(cmd.toString());
    }

    public String doImport(String fileName, String user, String iface) throws Exception {
        StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer();
        cmd.append(SOME_SCRIPT + " -a import ");
        cmd.append(" -f " );
        cmd.append(fileName);
        cmd.append(" -m " );
        cmd.append("user");
        cmd.append(" -u " );
        cmd.append(user);
        cmd.append(" -I " );
        cmd.append(iface);
        return execCmd(cmd.toString());
    } 
public String setRulesMode(String mode) throws Exception {
        String cmd = SOME_SCRIPT + " -a ";
        return execCmd(cmd.toString());
    }
```

Is there better way to do this? like encapsulate commands and arguments or more generic way of doing it? I tried to use enum but found it enum is better used when there are static/constant parameter list, so looking for better alaternative.

Comment: Thanks Colin, I am not sure what is that but look for it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'd create "CommandBuilder" that wraps `ProcessBuilder` and is able to compose and run command line.

Please pay attention that your attempt to redirect STDOUt to file will not work. Redirection is a shell feature. You can either run your command via shell (e.g. `/bin/sh YOUR COMMAND >YOURFILE` on unix or  `cmd -c YOUR COMMAND >YOURFILE` on windows.

Better way is to use `Process.setOutputStream()` from java. It is portable, easier to debug and maintain.  This can be functionality of your `CommandBuilder`.

EDIT

Here are some tips to the CommandBuilder structure.

```
public class CommandBuilder {
    public void setPrefix(); // e.g. cmd or /bin/sh But some kind of automatic logic should be implemented too, i.e. cmd for windows, /bin/sh for unix
    public void setCommand(); // for example ping
    public void addArgument(String value);  // e.g. myhost
    public void setInputStream(InputStream in);
    public void setOutputStream(OutputStream in);

    // add appropriate getters.

    public Process exec();
    public int execAndWait(); // returns process status
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Alex,  I want to build something like commandBuilder which will encapsulate commands but looking for generic implementation for different arguments for different commands...can you please elaborate little on how commandbuilder will look like ? or you are referring to using commandbuilder from apache?

Comment: Please take a look on example that I wrote as an addition to my answer.